# SQL Oracle ORA-00904: invalid indentifier error

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anybody help me pinpoint why this code is returning an SQL Oracle ORA-00904: invalid indentifier error? The query works without the Country = 'Argentina', but I need to filter down by this value. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
select llattrdata.ID dataid,

max(case when llattrdata.ATTRID = 4 then llattrdata.VALSTR end) Country

from llattrdata, dtree 

where
llattrdata.DEFID = 19400074 and
llattrdata.VERNUM = dtree.VERSIONNUM and
llattrdata.ID = dtree.DATAID and 
Country = 'Argentina'
group by llattrdata.ID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are filtering on grouped conditions, you need to use `having` instead of `where`.

It should be something like:

```
select llattrdata.ID dataid,
        max(case when llattrdata.ATTRID = 4 then llattrdata.VALSTR end) Country
  from llattrdata, dtree 
 where llattrdata.DEFID = 19400074 
   and llattrdata.VERNUM = dtree.VERSIONNUM 
   and llattrdata.ID = dtree.DATAID 
 group by llattrdata.ID
having max(case when llattrdata.ATTRID = 4 then llattrdata.VALSTR end) = 'Argentina'
```

Comment: thanks for the response ... this still gave me an error ORA-00904: "COUNTRY": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but is this not the same as:

```
select distinct
  llattrdata.ID     dataid,
  llattrdata.VALSTR Country
from
  llattrdata,
  dtree 
where
  llattrdata.VERNUM        = dtree.VERSIONNUM and
  llattrdata.ID            = dtree.DATAID     and 
  llattrdata.DEFID         = 19400074         and
  llattrdata.ATTRID        = 4                and
  llattrdata.VALSTRCountry = 'Argentina'
```